# org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.M2.jar has no source attachment

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-social

I am working on spring mvc 3.0 that integrated spring-social-facebook. When I debug the code, there is an error at line

```
List<Connection<?>> connections = connectionRepository.findConnections(providerId);
```

in the following method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{providerId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String connectionStatus(@PathVariable String providerId, 
                               NativeWebRequest request, 
                               Model model) {...}
```

and controller is ConnectController

Eclipse shows

**Source not found**

And when i keep the line inside try catch block, then error message is

> Expression parsing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1007E:(pos 22): Field or property 'name' cannot be found on null

I have added the org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.M2.jar file in WEB-INF/lib. I have also tried this using "Add External Jars..". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The 'no source attachment' issue is suggesting that your .jar does not have source code with it, or if it does, it is not telling eclipse where to find the source at.  Your real issue is that Spring Expression Language is trying to evaluate a property on an object that is `null`.  Basically, an equivalent of `NullPointerException`.  Where are you using SpEL at in your code?  Can you post that?

Comment: You need to attach any source jars to its companion code jar in Eclipse's project configuration where libraries are specified. Not sure what you mean "when you keep the line inside the try/catch block", but it sounds like something using SpEL isn't configured correctly.